# Finding emacs config file Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I am attempting to locate my config file. Using my emacs editor, I can find `.emacs` using `user-init-file` which outputs `~\.emacs`. However, trying to locate this file/folder in the terminal only returns `No such file or directory`. I read this could be caused by having a 32 bit file on a 64 bit system (which mine is); however, testing the file type (is `.emacs` a file?) with `file` produces the same output of `No such file or directory`. At this point I am stuck, and am open to any suggestions on what to do next. Am I being fooled by the return of `user-init-file` and must I create my own `.emacs`?

Comment: are you sure about the backslash `\\` in your path?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ah yes that was a typo on my end when transcribing the problem. It should be a forward slash, but the same issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

`~/.emacs` file may not exist just after a fresh emacs installation. To configure emacs, you need to first create it.

`user-init-file` merely points to the location emacs looks for the configuration file. It executes the content of the file only if the file exists.